# internal error because of htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am having an internal error 500 on the wordpress website.
I know that it is because of the `.htaccess` file that I manually added.
However I do not know why this is happening.

I tried changing the  RewriteBase but it never worked . Can you please help and explain how this work?

the wordpress installation is under the folder wordpress in the main directory (where the domain points).

Thanks in advance

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value memory_limit
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
```

Comment: Can you check the server error logs to see if there's any information there?

Comment: there are no error logs in it

Comment: however i got this in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  index.php

Comment: Unfortunately, a 500 error is a generic error message, and gives absolutely no information on what is wrong. However, the results of http://www.htaccesscheck.com/check.cgi show that you don't have a value for `php_value memory_limit` which gives a syntax error.

Comment: can you try taking everything out of your current htaccess file, save it, then go into your permalinks inside the settings tab, click the "save changes" button at the button of the page. Now see if you can view the homepage. 
lastly, go back into your permalinks page (inside wordpress) and see if there is any information regarding what should be copied into your htaccess file.  Copy and paste that into your htaccess file.

Comment: it's solved thanks to @aynber